# Storing a secret key on Android

Tags: android

My Android application uses a secret key to generate a token for authentication purposes. Is there a more secure way to store this than just putting this in the data store? I think for the iPhone, we store it in the keychain. I am aware of android.accounts.AccountManager, but this seems to give other applications potentially the ability to access the password (if the user selects the wrong option) and so seems less secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android (unfortunately) does not provide a way to do so. The approach I've used before is to encrypt this token with another key generated within the app.

Your app key can be algorithmically generated. This, however, is only as secure as your algorithm. Once that is known this is equivalent to storing the token in plain text.

Comment: I don't think that anyone would find it too hard to find the function if they really wanted to. However, this I suppose this is a lot more effort than just reading a plain text key

Comment: True. Its more security from obscurity than anything else. Another approach is to store the token encrypted using some user specified password. This is the safest, but, the user will have to authenticate themselves with the app everytime your app is launched.

Comment: Its not secure at all. It is the equivalent of obfuscation. It will protect you from the casual browser and the script kiddie but not sombody who wants to know the answer. But if you are only worried about script kiddies then it is an OK solution.

Comment: You can also check this out: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html

Comment: This answer is out-of-date, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43997737/311196

Answer (score 4):

You can store the key in the Preferences of your App. This will protect the key from getting read by other applications because of the underlying file system restrictions of the Android system.

But this won't protect the key from being read by the user itself.

Comment: True, BUT I CAN GET YOUR KEY IN A MINUTE IF YOU DO THIS! try apktool and you can get the whole strings.xml. Just did it on a famous android social app and got their oauth consumer key and secret, facebook secret, google analytics id, .... Took me 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

if you can run apk tool then its in debug and you are going to root the device.  There isn't any more protection on the keychain in iOS when its jailbroken

Comment: The its the user's fault that the system is not secure

Answer (score 0):

You can store secret data by encrypting it with a key generated by [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) and then storing the result whether you like.