# How to store secret key in Android?

Tags: android, account, encryption, secret-key

In my app I'm generating secret key based on device id + random garble. What's safiest way to store those secret key in a way that it can be easily retrieved if user will transfer data from one device to another one?

I'm talking about storing secret key in some external storage like: gmail or other server alike environment.

Comment: what's the purpose of your secret key, user tracking?

Comment: Nope, it's for encryption of user's data

Comment: @Ashwin I'm going to scramble user's data (like SMS and so on). I would like to give user possibility to transfer scrambled data to another device. That means I need to make secret key transferable across devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing a secret key on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671955/storing-a-secret-key-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"easily transferred secret key" is an oxymoron, because the main purpose of the secret key is to be, well, impossible to guess or copy. that's why i'd recommend to generate the unique secret key on every user device and use them to encode your data stored on that particular device (and nowhere else).

when you transfer the data, you may ask the user to create the password, and encrypt transferred data with that password. and ask the user to enter the same password on the receiving device in order to decrypt the transfer and encrypt back again, but using the unique device key.