# Storing and retrieving SecretKey without user password

Tags: java, android, encryption, keystore

I have an android application that requires some fields in the db to store encrypted strings.
I can generate a key and encrypt the Strings using the key.

Now I need to store the key for future decryption but i want to do it without the need for the user to enter a password (The user is blind for the encryption/decryption).

How can I do it securely, storing the password in SharedPreferences is enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671955/storing-a-secret-key-on-android

Comment: That doesn't help me, my strings are encrypted before installation and need to decrypt on the users device.
I need to pass the password to the user some how.

Comment: Given your constraints I think you need to define what you mean by "securely".

Comment: Securely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not secure, so you may use something like UUID for each application instance and to be used internally as a key for the encryption.

Comment: How is that suggestion more secure? And if it is not more secure, why suggesting it?

Comment: Because it is not needed to store any thing into DB or SharedPreferences as it is generated by the application during the running time or generated from server side. And if you find my suggestion is not secure, you can rate it down!